# What happened in Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru (Season 1)?

Tags: oregairu

I had watched the anime 3 years ago and I don't remember much of what happened. I plan to start the second season and don't feel like re-watching the first season.

Hence, I'm looking for a summary of the key events/story of the first season without any spoilers from the second season (couldn't find it online).

Comment: You can get the summary of each episodes here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_My_Teen_Romantic_Comedy_SNAFU_episodes_(season_1)

Comment: @AyaseEri That never crossed my mind. I checked the OreGairu Wikia and the main Wikipedia page of the anime. Thanks.

Comment: @AyaseEri you should post your comment as an answer.